# Cos'è "una zecca del pollice"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata* di Beppe Fenoglio, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto:

> Con **una zecca del pollice** sbottonò la fondina, ma
>   non estrasse la pistola. Nell’istante in cui il soldato piú
>   vicino dirigeva su di lui gli occhi frastornati dall’acqua,
>   Milton ruotò seccamente all’indietro. Non gli arrivò
>   l’urlo dell’allarme, solo un rantolo di stupore.

Non capisco il senso dell'espressione "una zecca del pollice". Secondo i dizionari, i significati del termine "zecca" sono il luogo dove si coniano le monete e il nome di un acaro parassita, ma non sembrano avere senso in questo contesto. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi cos'è "una zecca del pollice" nel brano precedente?

Answer (score 2):

Non ho mai sentito l'espressione usata in questo modo prima d'ora, ma se dovessi indovinare dal contesto direi che si riferisca ad un colpo secco del pollice, come quelli usati per lanciare in aria una moneta nel "testa o croce".

"Zecca" potrebbe venire dal fatto che, se un colpo del genere ti colpisse, potrebbe "pungere" come una puntura di zecca. Un po' come per il "tirare una stecca" si riferisce al colpire in modo goliardico una persona con il lato dell'indice tenendo pollice ed anulare con i polpastrelli congiunti.

Comment: Ma esiste l'aggettivo _gagliardico_? Non lo trovo né nello Zingarelli né nei dizionari on-line. E per la verità, non capisco neanche bene cosa significhi “tirare una stecca”.

Comment: @WalterTross Il gesto della “stecca” si usava durante la naia: tieni le punte di medio e anulare appoggiate alla punta del pollice e l'indice libero, facendo oscillare la mano in modo che l'indice colpisca il medio e faccia un rumore caratteristico. Pericolosissimo farlo a uno più vicino di te all'alba. Se lo provi, capisci che colpire uno fa più rumore e anche male. (Per chi non lo sapesse, *l'alba* è il giorno del congedo.)

Comment: @WalterTross hai ragione, volevo scrivere goliardico e ho avuto un lapsus. La spiegazione di egreg ti illustra cosa sia una stecca :)

Answer (score 2):

**Luperini**, in *La scrittura e l'interpretazione* (Vol.6/1), riporta il passo antologico mettendo la nota:

> *Zecca*: punta

**Ferroni**, in *Storia e testi della letteratura italiana* (vol. 10, pag. 200), riporta lo stesso passo antologico apponendo la nota 17:

> *Con una zecca del pollice*: con un lembo del pollice (sentito, quasi, come corpo estraneo).

**Santagata**, in *Il Filo Rosso* (vol. 3/3 Secondo Novecento, pag. 298), riporta sempre lo stesso passo e appone la nota 21:

> *Con una zecca del pollice...fondina*: con un colpo secco sbottonò la custodia della pistola.

Comment: Sono un po' perplesso: se significasse davvero “punta”, vorrebbe dire che la frase di Fenoglio parla di *una* punta del pollice, che comunque ne ha una sempre sola. Semmai direbbe “con la zecca del pollice”. Puoi dare un po' più di contesto, o magari un estratto, del testo di Luperini che citi? Parla proprio di questo passo? Di altre occorrenze di “zecca”? Grazie.

Comment: @DaG Il testo di Luperini è una *Storia e antologia della letteratura italiana* e riporta giusto uno stralcio di qualche pagina del romanzo di Fenoglio. Al punto *zecca* mette una nota esplicativa (come altre nel testo) così: **zecca: punta.** E credo debba intendersi *con una zecca del pollice=con la punta del pollice* come espressione idiomatica creata da Fenoglio.

Comment: Ah, interessante, grazie.

Comment: @DaG Ferroni fornisce una spiegazione simile